# Rails, trouble in a form trying to use the put http method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rest

```
<% form_ tag user_path(@user), :method => :put do %>
```

That's my form, so I want it to access the update method of my UsersController, I set the map.resources :users , and the RESTful paths generated:

```
users     GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}          
          POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create",:controller=>"users"}
new_ user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user      GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

So I try to send to user_path(@user) using the PUT HTTP method and it comes back with:

```
Unknown action

No action responded to 1. Actions: create, destroy, edit, index, logged?, new, show and update
```

So obviously I don't know how to make this work, so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using RESTful resources (and you should be), try using `form_for` not `form_tag` ... with the full setup like this:

```
<% form_for :user, @user, :url=>user_path(@user), :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f| %>

  #this scopes the form elements to the @user object, eg.
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

<% end %>
```

Check out the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Too late to answer, but check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-put-or-delete-methods-work

Not all browsers support PUT so you use POST with a hidden input stating that the method is PUT

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried this?

```
<% form_tag :url=>user_path(@user), :html=>{:method=>:put} do %>
```

Comment: Updated link : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your server? My routes.rb never gets reloaded correctly if I update it while the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem when trying to use a tableless model ([Rails model without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315850/rails-model-without-database)).

After some quick digging into actionpack's form_helper.rb I found a solution.  Add this to your model:

```
def new_record?; false; end
```

In my case my model is always built from scratch so this was necessary to "trick" Rails into treating it as an existing object, and thus doing a PUT rather than a POST.