# how to require active record working outside of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, require

i need to require active record, but I am working outside of rails (here is why: [Simple Ruby Input Validation Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416484/simple-ruby-input-validation-library)). do I need to require the entire rails gem, or can i be DRYer?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here's how I'm using ActiveRecord outside of Rails:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2' # or 'pg' or 'sqlite3'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql2', # or 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'
  database: 'DB_NAME',
  username: 'DB_USER',
  password: 'DB_PASS',
  host:     'localhost'
)

# Note that the corresponding table is 'orders'
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Order.all.each do |o|
  puts "o: #{o.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: You need to specify mysql2 as the adapter, not mysql (for googlers).

Comment: You also need libmysqlclient-dev on ubuntu ( and probably other platforms )

Comment: @BenWest What is the use of libmysqlclient-dev? (I apologize for my lack of basic knowledge on the subject)

Comment: @Renan because the ruby gem compiles some of its dependencies, it requires the development headers for the libraries its dependencies link to.

http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html

Comment: I wish people wouldn't reference Ubuntu/Debian package names directly. Their naming convention is strange at best and this causes confusing answers to be upvoted, which ultimately doesn't help people searching.

Comment: Its highly recommended that you configure a timezone or you will get lots of obscure timezone-related issues. ::Time.zone = 'UTC'; ::ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :utc

Answer (score 7):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9 assumes `require 'rubygems'`.