# Using ActiveRecord 3.1 without Rails in a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysql2

The following *ought* to work as a script, with ActiveRecord 3.1 (note that this is *without Rails*, not the other way around):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require "active_record"
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig)

irb
```

Unfortunately, it gives the error:

```
... connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': ...
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` ...
```

Adding the line `gem 'mysql2', '<0.3'` before `require "active_record"` as suggested by some previous posts (which reference 0.2.7, the 0.2 gem at the time; presently it's 0.2.18) doesn't change it.

How can I get it to work? I want ActiveRecord but not the whole of Rails.

Comment: Does this help? http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2009/01/14/activerecord-ruby-on-rails-optional/

Comment: Not really; I'm already doing that. It errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ActiveRecord in a ruby script outside Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643875/how-to-use-activerecord-in-a-ruby-script-outside-rails)

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal

```
gem install mysql2
```

and add row to you code `require 'mysql2'`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require 'mysql2'
require "active_record"

dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig)
```

Comment: Here's how you do it without needing a `database.yml` file - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3661927/2229277

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://techie.lucaspr.im/so-you-got-the-gem-install-activerecord-mysql2-adapter-problem/) has fixed my issue, at least temporarily. I haven't yet restarted, so I don't know if it'll survive that. And it seems like a dirty hack; there's got to be a better way.

I haven't yet tested Aleksei's answer above, since I'm not having the same issue after having run this command. Will update ifwhen I do.

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/`rvm current`/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```