# Bundle a rails 4 application into a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am currently developing a rails 4 based media streaming app and wanted to know if i could have the rails app as a kind of source code and bundle it into a gem for distribution? is there some sort of easy solution for this? or do i have to roll my own?

Comment: I think this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21438240/645886

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think you can do this via an Engine. From the Rails docs:

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide functionality to their host applications.
>
> ...
>
> Engines are also closely related to plugins where the two share a common lib directory structure and are both generated using the rails plugin new generator. The difference being that an engine is considered a "full plugin" by Rails as indicated by the --full option that's passed to the generator command, but this guide will refer to them simply as "engines" throughout. An engine can be a plugin, and a plugin can be an engine.

Read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: i have investigated the engines option, but it dosent suffice as i want this whole app to be a gem and have be able to be booted up by a command etc.