# can't require ar gem even though its on my gem list

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems

When I type

```
gem list
```

I see the following

```
...
activerecord (3.2.17, 3.2.13)
...
```

But when I type this

```
cat >> does_ar_exist.rb
require 'activerecord'
ActiveRecord

ruby does_ar_exist.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- activerecord (LoadError)
from /Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: It is `require 'active_record'`, with an underscore, you just have to fix that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661546/how-to-require-active-record-working-outside-of-rails

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
require 'active_record'
```

instead of `require 'activerecord'`, since the file you want to load is [`active_record.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib).