# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedColumn::FALSE_VALUES (NameError) in Ruby (not using Rails) and Oracle

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I am writing a test in Ruby (2.3.00p0) and Oracle client (12.1.0.2). I am using below code to connect to Oracle

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
 :adapter=>'oracle_enhanced',
 :database=>'DBName:1521',
 :username=>'username',
 :password=>'password'
)
```

I am not using Rails as I this is functional tests written in Ruby and Cucumber. OS is Mac. I have installed ruby-oci8 and all other gems needed. Still getting the error 
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedColumn::FALSE_VALUES (NameError)

Can someone please help me resolve this issue. All the articles and solutions are related to rails and not plain ruby.

TIA

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661546/how-to-require-active-record-working-outside-of-rails?) It appears you can do `require 'active_record'` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Cory Shay!! And yes , I did both: require 'active_record' and 
require 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'. Still the same error and other link you gave uses 'mysql' adapter.

Comment: What version of oracle enhanced adapter do you have? May be related to these issues: [#893](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/893)  and [#889](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/889).

Comment: @Cory Shay, Thank you so much. I had activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7 so I uninstalled and installed activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter -v 1.7.0.beta1 and this solved the issue. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear!