# How to use rails api find_or_create_by in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, methods, rspec

I tried to run test a gem for rails.
In the test, I am in ruby not rails.
The purpose of this code is to create rails modules.

But this kind of codes will be a template supposed to run in rails.
Problem come when test encountered something like

```
my_module= Myprogram::Module.find_or_create_by
                                             :module_code=>my_module.code, 
                                             :code=> scode, 
                                             :name=>sname
```

then

```
error: Undefined method find_or_create_by
```

My first though is to require (what) gem that has this method.

Can anyone help me out.?

Comment: I suppose it'a an ActiveRecord method, so check out if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661546/how-to-require-active-record-working-outside-of-rails) can lead somewhere..

Comment: Thanks, I use mongoid

Comment: require `mongoid`  then -))

Comment: Can you show how the `Myprogram` class is defined?

Comment: @mikwat here gist https://gist.github.com/kul1/b0607a3a3e117cebd84bf8330152ef0b

Answer (score 0):

Myprogram::Module is mongoid class using namespace to that class.
I fixed the error by.

1. require proper gem which is mongoid (thanks @marmeladze and mikwat)
2. require_relative to the class (without this will show NameError:
   uninitialized constant Myprogram::Module::Mongoid

In my case here the code:

```
.
.
require 'mongoid'
require_relative '../lib/generators/myprogram/templates/app/models/myprogram/module.rb'
```