# How do I handle migration of ActiveRecord::Base which implemented a tableless model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, migration

We had the following class to process SOAP responses from external API(s) which worked fine in ruby 1.8.7, but it is looking for a table with these columns post migration (which has never been there) to ruby 1.9.2/rails 3.1, How do I handle this migratation?

```
class SoapResponse < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def self.columns
    @columns ||= [];
  end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(
      name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
  end

  def save(validate = true)
    validate ? valid? : true
  end

  column :soap_payload, :text
  serialize :soap_payload
end
```

Comment: Why are you subclassing ActiveRecord::Base for something that isn't backed by a table?

Comment: Its an old application and not sure what the design decisions were, how should I achieve this with ruby 1.9/rails 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't (have any migrations for it).

You don't have migrations and you don't inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` as that is the database ORM component.

If you use a generator to create the model use `--skip-migration` to avoid generating the database migration file.

You can still get validations and conversions though, e.g.

```
class SoapResponse
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
```

If you want some setup data (i.e. Constants, given there is no db! ) you can just define them here (Constants start with uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the serialization capability of ActiveRecord::Base. That seems to be the only thing this class is using it for. If so, try calling this in your class definition:

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

Or you could try using [ActiveModel::Serialization](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveModel/Serialization).

The pattern in your code looks like what's suggested in [this answer for table-less AR models in Rails 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315850/rails-model-without-database).