# rails 4-- model with no table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, view and controller for a view (`Feed`) that doesn't have any "local" data. That is, the data is grabbed via a web service call to a client site and rendered in a local view.

The local site needs to verify that the object to grab from the remote site is valid (by verifying that the `User` that owns the `Feed` has a valid account) and then it displays it.

I had the logic to grab the data from the remote feed in a `Feed` model. Then the `Feed` controller takes the URL param for the feed id, passes it to the model `getFeed` function, and  displays it.

However, since there's no table, the `Feed.getFeed(params[:feed_id])` call in the controller was returning an error saying `there is no table Feed`.

Should I delete the `Feed` model and just make the `getFeed` function a helper function? What's the proper Rails way to deal with models with no table?

Comment: I believe the solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14389234/877472) is what you're looking for. Essentially a plain 'ol class is all you need. You can then add Rails and active-whatever modules as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you're using Rails, it doesn't mean every model has to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`

In your situation, I'd simply do something along these lines:

```
# app/models/feed.rb
class Feed
  def initialize(feed_id)
    @feed_id = feed_id
  end

  def fetch
    # ... put the web-service handling here
  end

  # encapsulate the rest of your feed processing / handling logic here
end

# app/controllers/feeds_controller.rb
class FeedsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @feed = Feed.new(params[:feed_id])
    @feed.fetch

    # render
  end
end
```

Remember: it's **Ruby** on Rails, not just Rails. You can do a lot more than just ActiveRecord models.

Comment: I tried removing the inheritance and now am getting an error complaining that the function does not exist-- is this the purpose of you `initialize` method?

Comment: while his description is different than his title, this is not a good answer for the title question, as there are valid reasons to want an AR model without a backing database table.

Comment: The answer is fine - the solution in these cases is to simply not inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but take what is required, like validations. See [rails-model-without-a-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389105/rails-model-without-a-table)

Answer (score -4):

You can make an attr_accessor in your model

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :feed
```

It will represent `feed` as a temporary variable for your controller to pass the data.